# why all visual studio 2013 code are with red background?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

[image: example of red background code]

I have resharper installed and I'm not sure at this point whether it is resharper or VS?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you run tests with code coverage enabled? ReSharper/dotCover will highlight covered code in green, and uncovered code in red. You can disable this in the "coverage" tab of the Unit Test Sessions window. Check the toolbar buttons. You should also be able to click "Disable code highlighting" in the ReSharper → Cover menu.

Comment: Thank you, yes I came back to answer my own question but you beat me to it, I figured it out it was dotCover and I disabled it. Annoying though!!

Comment: If it is code coverage then why are comments and white space highlighted (and only part of the `LogObject`)?

Comment: I suspect the code was edited after the highlighting was calculated. dotCover is usually smart enough to update the highlighting correctly, so it looks like it's applied to the code. I don't know why yours is out of sync.